# Unable to get disk usage on mounted folder with CYGWIN

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cmd, cygwin

I have installed CYGWIN on a 2008R2 server and have some disks which I have mounted to folders as below (example):

```
l:\mounted\mounted_hd1
l:\mounted\mounted_hd2
l:\mounted\mounted_hd3
```

I have data and additional folders under the mountpoints (example):

```
l:\mounted\mounted_hd1\photos
l:\mounted\mounted_hd2\backup_data
l:\mounted\mounted_hd3\data
```

When I run the following command: **C:\cygwin\bin\df -k /cydrive/L/mounted/mounted_hd1**

I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/df: cannot stat '..': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/df: no file systems processed
```

However, when I run  **C:\cygwin\bin\df -k /cydrive/L/mounted**
I get the size of the disk L: which was created for mounting the disks...

Why am I not able to run **df -k** on the mounted folders?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the output of df -k without arguments?

Comment: It lists all disks on my system, including the one that contains the folder with the mounted disks

Comment: It could work if you just run ' C:\cygwin\bin\df -k /cydrive/L'. If you want disk usage by directory used 'du -sh <your folder path>'

Comment: It turns out (after *many* hours of troubleshooting) it appears that the x86 version of Cygwin is unable to properly df -k  again child folders of mounted folders. Updating to the x64 version of Cygwin fixed my issue. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I tell, in the x86 version of Cygwin , the **df -k** command for determining disk usage is not able to properly run against child folders for disks mounted as folders in disk management.

I was able to resolve my issue by updating Cygwin to the x64 version:

Determine the version of Cygwin installed - via cmd - run:

```
uname -a
```

The x86 version will contain: **i686**

The x64 version will contain: **x86_64**

If you require the above functionality as I did in my specific use-case , then install the *latest* x64 version needed as required:
https://cygwin.com/